# How to horizontally concatenate matrices present inside each cell of a cell array?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, concatenation, reshape, cell-array

I have a `1x8 Cell Array(A)` with elements composed of the following dimension.

```
10x13x2 double  10x13x2 double  10x13x2 double  10x13x2 double  10x13x2 double  10x13x2 double  10x13x2 double  10x13x2 double
```

where in `A{1,1}....A{1,8}` i have,

```
val(:,:,1) = 10x13 matrix(130 values)
val(:,:,2) = Another 10x13 Matrix(130 values)
```

Now i want to horizontally concatenate `val(:,:,1) and val(:,:,2)` so that i get a total of `260 values` as a result of concatenation in each cell. i need to concatenate it like say if, `val(:,:,1) is M and val(:,:2) is V`. so i need to concatenate horizontally like `[M1 V1]..[MN VN]`

And i want this to be done for all the 8 elements in the cell array.

So, finally i have to get an value of a 1x8 cell array like the below

```
MxNX1 MxNX1 MxNX1 MxNX1 MxNX1 MxNX1 MxNx1 MxNX1
```

where `MXN = 260`,

so finally i should get a `1x8` Cell array ,and i hope the dimension of each cell would be `260x8`.

Kindly suggest how to do this, if it involves reshaping and loops kindly suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(:,:)` notation for a 3D array horizontally concatenates the 3D slices. Use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) or a loop to apply that to all cells of `A`.

```
A = cellfun(@(x) {x(:,:)}, A);
```

Alternately,  if the above version is less clear, you can use [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).

```
A = cellfun(@(x) {reshape(x,10,[])}, A);
```

Comment: Thank you Sardar for your assistance,